# Подключить шрифт Raleway(кириллический) На Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, шрифты, google-fonts

Скачал шрифт Raleway (кириллический). Как его подключить? Закинул все файлы в  папку fonts, прописал подключение в css:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayThin";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayThin/RalewayThin.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayThin/RalewayThin.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayThin/RalewayThin.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayThin/RalewayThin.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayExtraLight";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayExtraLight/RalewayExtraLight.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayExtraLight/RalewayExtraLight.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayExtraLight/RalewayExtraLight.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayExtraLight/RalewayExtraLight.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayLight";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayLight/RalewayLight.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayLight/RalewayLight.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayLight/RalewayLight.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayLight/RalewayLight.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayMedium";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayMedium/RalewayMedium.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayMedium/RalewayMedium.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayMedium/RalewayMedium.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayMedium/RalewayMedium.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewaySemiBold";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewaySemiBold/RalewaySemiBold.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewaySemiBold/RalewaySemiBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewaySemiBold/RalewaySemiBold.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewaySemiBold/RalewaySemiBold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayBold";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayBold/RalewayBold.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayBold/RalewayBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayBold/RalewayBold.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayBold/RalewayBold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayExtraBold";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayExtraBold/RalewayExtraBold.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayExtraBold/RalewayExtraBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayExtraBold/RalewayExtraBold.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayExtraBold/RalewayExtraBold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "RalewayBlack";
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayBlack/RalewayBlack.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/RalewayBlack/RalewayBlack.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/RalewayBlack/RalewayBlack.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/RalewayBlack/RalewayBlack.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Но сайт его не видит, и на wordpress его не видно, пытался прописать этот же код в самой админке в файле стили, но не дало никакого результата, пути вроде все верные.

Comment: В какой файл вы прописали этот код? Какой путь этого файла css?

Comment: Еще нужно чтобы в админке можно было выбирать этот шрифт.

Comment: wp-content/theme/impreza/css/style.css

Comment: wp-content/theme/impreza/fonts

Comment: Пути прописаны правильно. Как индикатор - при загрузке страницы в консоли не должно быть 404 по шрифтам. А что значит - сайт не видит? Вы должны объявить в css, что такие-то классы используют этот шрифт.

Comment: Я пробовал классам присвоить этот шрифт,но не было никакого результата.

Comment: Смотрите в консоль, вычисленные стили - какой там шрифт и почему. Ну или сайт уже покажите, дольше объяснять.

Comment: Посмотрю сейчас консол,вот сам сайт http://ledex57v.beget.tech/

Comment: когда в консоли прописываю данный шрифт,то он меняется.

Comment: а я не вижу в браузере, что ваш style.css вообще подключен: http://take.ms/XeRpQ

Comment: пробовал в style.min.css подключить все равно не видит,а если в консоли элементу прописать этот шрифт ,то он нормально меняется.

Comment: style.min.css находится в той же папке ,что и style.css

Comment: Все шрифты подключились,теперь как сделать ,чтобы в админке можно было выбирать данный шрифт?

Comment: Это уже совершенно другой вопрос. Создайте его отдельно с объяснением, где именно вы хотели бы видеть это подключение, на какой странице админки.

Comment: Хорошо ,спасибо.